# How to make the numpad work in Qt 5.14.1?

Tags: qt, qt5, numpad

I was working for quite a while with Qt5 5.9.8 and updated to the latest release Qt5 5.14.1. I built Qt 5.14.1 with exactly the same flags as the 5.9.8 version and everything seemed to be working fine except for one issue: It is impossible to enter numbers with the numpad.

This issue has nothing to do with the applications I write with Qt but is somehow Qt inherent. It is also present in the Qt [designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) as well as in [ParaView](https://www.paraview.org/) which I compile with the my compiled Qt version.

Is there anything I can do to compile Qt to make the numpad work again?

Comment: Which platform are you on, and which Qt builds are you using? For Linux, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75284 suggests that a missing xcb dependency might be a possible cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-75284) that [Frank Osterfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/299399/frank-osterfeld) mentioned lead me to the solution of this problem. The issue was a missing xkb dependency. After a `yum install libxkbcommon libxkbcommon-devel` Qt5 is built and the numpad is working as expected.

The difference can be inspected in the configure output. Without `libxkbcommon libxkbcommon-devel`:

```
  XCB:
    Using system-provided XCB libraries .. no
    XCB XKB .............................. no
    XCB XInput ........................... yes
```

and with `libxkbcommon libxkbcommon-devel`:

```
  XCB:
    Using system-provided XCB libraries .. no
    XCB XKB .............................. yes
    XCB XInput ........................... yes
```